# Curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer [TCP Retransmission]

Tags: networking, openstack, openwrt, openstack-neutron

**Network topology**
[image]

**PC1:**

- Env: Centos 8.2 Linux compute-31 4.18.0-240.22.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 8 19:01:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- IP: 10.0.0.31

1. ping is ok

```
[root@compute-31 ~]# ping 10.10.10.82
PING 10.10.10.82 (10.10.10.82) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.82: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.741 ms
From 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.0.0.210)
64 bytes from 10.10.10.82: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.404 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.82: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.429 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.82: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.389 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.82: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.412 ms
^C
--- 10.10.10.82 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 133ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.389/0.475/0.741/0.133 ms
```

2. telnet is ok

```
[root@10.0.0.31 ~]# telnet 10.10.10.82 9100
Trying 10.10.10.82...
Connected to 10.10.10.82.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

3. curl is **not ok**

```
[root@10.0.0.31 ~]# curl -v http://10.10.10.82:9100/metrics
*   Trying 10.10.10.82...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.10.10.82 (10.10.10.82) port 9100 (#0)
> GET /metrics HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.10.10.82:9100
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

4. traceroute is ok

```
[root@10.0.0.31 ~]# traceroute -n -I 10.10.10.82
traceroute to 10.10.10.82 (10.10.10.82), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1  0.172 ms  0.151 ms  0.146 ms
 2  10.0.0.210  0.209 ms  0.289 ms  0.268 ms
 3  10.10.10.82  0.600 ms  0.582 ms  0.590 ms
```

**PC2:**

- Env: Windows 10
- IP: 10.0.10.6

curl is ok

```
C:\Users\Jeffery>curl 10.10.10.82:9100/metrics
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the pause duration of garbage collection cycles.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 7.228e-06
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 8.679e-06
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 1.0364e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 1.2266e-05
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.000641901
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.139410267
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 11244
```

***TRY1***:

In the PC1(10.0.0.31), Change the route path to `10.0.0.210 ->10.10.10.82` by add new route `route add -net 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.210`, problem solved! But why? What happend to 10.0.0.1?

PS: The old path is `10.0.0.1 ->10.0.0.210 -> 10.10.10.82`

***TRY2***:

I found somethings in `tcpdump`, but I didn't find what caused it.

`[root@10.0.0.31 ~]# tcpdump -n -i eno2 host 10.0.0.31 and 10.10.10.82 -w tcpdum.10.0.0.31`
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text (code or errors); see [ask]. Also please note that stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Your question may fit better on superuser.com or serverfault.com, but before you post there, make sure your question includes all relevant information and what you tried to troubleshoot this (e.g., check for firewalls).

Comment: Could you use `traceroute` to check the network traffic flow, or check the source host could be connected in the VM host 10.10.10.82 ?

Comment: @VictorLee Thanks for your help!
`[10.0.0.31 ~]# traceroute -n 10.10.10.82` return this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzI4L.png

Comment: @JefferyLuo Welcome to SO. According `Connection reset by peer`, you should check the server's log and the VRouter's rule. As your picture show, PC1 and PC2 connect to the VM server through different tunnel? Or you could check the different of this two network traffic.

Comment: @VictorLee There is no abnormal message in the server's log, there may be no incoming session.  Both VM and VRouter have `ALLOW IPv4 9100/tcp from 0.0.0.0/0` rule, What tools can be used to find out what is happening in the network?

Comment: @JefferyLuo `tcpdump` may help you check the network traffic.

Comment: @VictorLee In the PC1(10.0.0.31), Change the route path to `10.0.0.210 ->10.10.10.82 `by add new route `route add -net 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.210`, problem solved! But why? What happend to 10.0.0.1?

PS: The old path is `10.0.0.1 ->10.0.0.210 -> 10.10.10.82`

Comment: @JefferyLuo Maybe the old path's default gatewate is `10.0.0.1` and it can't router to `10.10.10.82`, all network traffic topology can show by run `tcpdump` in all nodes, you could find the reason and understand clearly.